# How do I find what PHP script is changing the file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, security, debian, malware

I have `apache` installed with `mod_php` PHP5.

I've been able to find out that apache process is changing my `.htaccess` and `index.php` files in `/var/www` directory. All files in this directory are owned by `www-data:www-data` and have `ug=rwX,o=rX` permissions.

It's obvious that some malware PHP script is doing this. How do I find it?

Here's the output of `auditd`:

```
time->Thu Jun 26 21:15:12 2014
type=PATH msg=audit(1403802912.787:936): item=0 name="/var/www/example/htdocs/index.php" inode=1182278 dev=ca:01 mode=0100404 ouid=33 ogid=33 rdev=00:00
type=CWD msg=audit(1403802912.787:936):  cwd="/var/www/example/htdocs"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1403802912.787:936): arch=c000003e syscall=90 success=yes exit=0 a0=7fac1ef5a128 a1=104 a2=7 a3=7fac0e1490c0 items=1 ppid=12397 pid=22347 auid=4294967295 uid=33 gid=33 euid=33 suid=33 fsuid=33 egid=33 sgid=33 fsgid=33 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="apache2" exe="/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2" key=(null)
```

Comment: You shouldn't let the web server process write to any files in the web site directory unless it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your access logs around the time, maybe you can find something there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've got a lot of virtualhosts and access files are separate. Is there a way to monitor ALL HTTP requests in realtime?